# Why is this process refusing to quit?

Tags: unix, process

I have a cron job that runs a shell script that executes a php script. It runs every day, sends some email, and writes to stdout (which is redirected to a log file in the shell script).

It looks as though this process has finished, today, but not exited (or whatever the correct terminology is!).

```
$ ps -ejH
...
10756 10756 10756 ?        00:00:00   sh
10760 10756 10756 ?        00:00:00     automail.sh
10766 10756 10756 ?        00:03:57       php
...
```

The process with id `10766` has consumed just under 4 minutes of CPU time. From an interactive top session, I get the following:

```
10766 root      20   0 40640 6024    4 S  0.0  0.2   3:57.48 php
```

Those hundredths haven't changed since I've looked at it. So my conclusion is that it's doing ... almost nothing, at the very most.

```
$ ls -ld /proc/10766/
dr-xr-xr-x 7 root root 0 2016-03-09 08:55 /proc/10766/
```

tells me it's been going for some time; server time is now:

```
$ date
Wed Mar  9 11:08:29 GMT 2016
```

The last line of the php script writes to a log file, and that line *is* present in the log file. Execution of the php script is the final thing in the shell script.

How do I go about diagnosing why this process hasn't quit?

**UPDATE**

Here's an edited version of the shell script I'm running:

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
PHP=/usr/bin/php
SCRIPT=/path/to/script.php
LOG=/path/to/log.file.$DATE.log

$PHP $SCRIPT >> $LOG
```

Comment: You could attach to it using `strace -p 10766` to see what it's actually doing.

Comment: @Mugurel I see `read(4, `. There isn't a file named `4` in `/proc/self/fd` - is that (part of) the problem?

Comment: could you include the command line you are using to launch php? or better a chunk of your shell script

Comment: @pete I've added the shell script to my original question (I don't think I can have that properly formatted in a comment). Note that paths are not real.

Comment: @BobbyJack, you should check `/proc/10766/fd/4`. PHP process seems to wait for an input data that may come from a file, pipe, socket or another file descriptor. `/proc/self/fd' shows file descriptors created by your shell instead.

Comment: @AndersonM.Gomes Thanks for clearing that up. `/proc/10766/fd/4` is a socket

Comment: Sure. Then, the output of `netstat -anp` will clarify things. Run the netstat command as root and check whether it an UNIX socket or a network one. Figure in the PHP code where socket syscalls are and check if calls to [stream_set_timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php) (or similar function) exists. The script seems to be waiting data from a connection that did not finish correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process is listed as 'sleeping' not finished or zombied.

```
10766 root      20   0 40640 6024    4 S  0.0  0.2   3:57.48 php
```

Its stuck doing something, given you said it had `read(4, ...` in a strace output I'd say its probably waiting for the other end of a socket connection send it data. Like a website has given up sending you data.

Thats a total guess though.

There almost certainly should be a file descriptor for 4 which gives more information if you try `lsof -p10756` and see what its up to.

Comment: Thanks. Your diagnosis is pretty much spot on. Is that process ever going to give up, or should I kill it?

Comment: If its a website on the other end, I suspect you are never going to get a response at this point.